# Formatting a list in Jinja2 with linebreaks and checkboxes

Tags: python, jinja2

I use the following code to get a list of files and return the list with linebreaks in-between each item. What I am trying to do is add a checkbox to each item but `string.join` only allows 2 arguments.
This is what I've tried that produces the error `TypeError: join() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`:

```
listfiles = os.listdir('my_path')
col_list = string.join('<input type="checkbox" />', listfiles, '</br>')
```

How should I go about formatting my list of files so that each line has a checkbox as well as a line break? Thanks!

Comment: Also please consider a different title--this really has little to do with what you're trying to do, and more to do with how you're trying to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lesson on reading error messages.  Some are cryptic and understandably difficult to follow up on.  This one is fairly clear: You're passing three arguments to a function that takes only two.  You can always check the documentation for standard library functions and methods in the [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/index.html), or at the command prompt using the `help()` function on any object.  For example `help(string.join)`.

Don't use the `string` module for this however, as that usage is deprecated.  Strings have a built-in `.join()` method.

You're looking for

```
col_list = '<br />'.join('<input type="checkbox" name="..." />%s' % filename
                         for filename in listfiles)
```